# Are any nations in discussions with China to prevent any further dangerous viruses from becoming pandemic?

Tags: international-relations, china, covid-19, healthcare, who

Has the US (or any western government) made any representations to China concerning responsibility regarding Covid-19?

And is anyone in discussions with China, or any other country, as to how to prevent any further such virus from emerging - which may be even more dangerous than this one?

What efforts are WHO taking, and how might they be hampered by the US withdrawal (perhaps only temporarily) from that body?

Comment: The US did. Unfortunately that got mixed in other US-China relations and the US domestic handling of Covid.

Comment: This question needs some focus. China could do some things to reduce risk, but viruses can evolve anywhere, and there's nothing we can currently do about that. And is this a question about US policy, or the policy of Western states? I'm going to vote to close as needing focus, but that just means I want you to edit, clarify and expand.

Comment: @TedWrigley I am merely seeking factual information as to what, if anything western nations are doing/have done to prevent similar circumstances from arising. I believe the evidence is almost conclusive that the virus arose in China, and it most likely had something to do with the poor standards of hygiene in their wet markets. It would seem to me  essential to bring pressure to bear on China to improve its public health standards, especially with the sale of meat.. I did read that the wet markets which were closed by the PRC have begun to re-open.

Comment: [The best time to prevent the next pandemic is now: countries join voices for better emergency preparedness](https://www.who.int/news-room/detail/01-10-2020-the-best-time-to-prevent-the-next-pandemic-is-now-countries-join-voices-for-better-emergency-preparedness)

Comment: @SeverusSnape Why don't you incorporate that into an answer.

Comment: @WS2: That was a reasonable explanation. Could you edit that into your question to make it more robust?

Comment: @WS2 I'd say that the evidence is conclusive that the virus arose in China, but 'poor standards of hygiene in their wet markets' is a terrible characterization of what happened. Have you ever visited Seattle? Congratulations, you've probably been to a wet market (Pike Place). China is certainly _a_ likely place for a virus to arise by virtue of sheer numbers, but there's no evidence AFAIK that they're any more likely than would be expected by random selection.

Comment: The problem with this question is in the assumption that the emergence of new (or species-crossing) viruses is somehow unique to China, or more likely to happen in China than elsewhere.  That is simply false: many new diseases have arisen elsewhere, e.g. AIDS & Ebola in Africa, MERS in the Middle East, Lyme Disease in North America (https://medicine.yale.edu/news-article/15651/ )

Comment: The WHO has been giving the correct advice from the beginning.  It's politicians that have ignored it that are the problem.  Most of these politicians have even been ignoring the advice from their own government agencies and health organizations.  China acted very quickly with very strict measures, so I fail to see a way to blame the Chinese government for other countries ignoring the advice they got and the example of China.  Also remember that China had no warning - the rest of the world had warning and were slow to react (and in some cases did not react at all).

Comment: @jamesqf But Africa and the Middle East have similar problems. Isn't the fact that to produce meat for consumption requires expensive health regulation, not available in much of the world. And the world's poor to a large extent still depend on the meat of wild animals.

Comment: @StephenG The [Worldometer](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/) statistics show China as having experienced only about 4,600 deaths from covid. This figure has not changed from earlier this year when the problem was simply in the city of Wuhan. Do you actually believe that while it has ripped through most of the developed world (214,000 deaths in America alone) that China has experienced no further deaths - that it has not even touched cities like Beijing and Shanghai?

Comment: Hard to know.  We'd hear something if there was a serious problem, which suggest they have it at least under control and manageable.  China is not like North Korea, which can keep a really tight lid on it's internal problems - China does too much trade and has too much contact to hide serious problems.  It would be impossible to hide a serious problem in Shanghai or Beijing.  But my point was that they initially reacted as best as could be hoped to a new disease and, even forewarned, the rest of us screwed up.  They have already demonstrated they will do what is required.  We have not.

Comment: @StephenG I hear what you say but....! What they did was to isolate the city of Wuhan - which sounds straightforward enough - until you appreciate that Wuhan is the size of London or New York - 11.8 million inhabitants. But still the death toll was only 4,000 odd. Either this is a total misstatement of the true facts, or else western countries should be delving far more deeply than they seem to be, to understand more precisely what China has done to combat the virus. (I heard on the BBC this morning that they are re-opening cinemas in Beijing).

Comment: @WS2: These are not "problems", they are a consequence of people living a normal life, instead of being isolated from the natural world.

Comment: @WS2 In my country the government agency charged with recommending measures for public safety with respect to Covid-19 recommended yesterday going to the highest level of restrictions (level 5 of 5).  The government have gone only to only level 3 (rejecting level 5 and 4).  The problem in Western democracies is that politicians are afraid to b be tough on voters.  I was at least hoping for level 4, as many places are already at level 3 and it's not working.  I think in China there is a better attitude, public and political.

Comment: @StephenG I fully agree that western countries (with the notable exception of Germany) have been denied the willing co-operation of large sections of the public in those places. However I do not believe we have any accurate picture of what has been happening in either China or Russia. Contacts of mine on the ground tell me the position in Moscow is far far worse than the published figures would suggest.

Comment: @StephenG you say that the WHO has been giving correct advice, and that western governments ignored both the WHO and their own experts. However, the accepted answer to https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/53255/have-governments-restrictions-on-travel-been-supported-by-expert-advice?r=SearchResults indicates that US government experts have contradicted the WHO’s advice against travel restrictions, and that US advice was at least partially followed.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer

In the United Nations General Assembly side-event on ‘Sustainable preparedness for health security and resilience: Adopting a whole-of-society approach and breaking the “panic-then-forget” cycle’, participants shared the common idea that everyone must be prepared for the next health emergency.

According to a report titled ["A world in disorder"](https://apps.who.int/gpmb/assets/pdf/200913_GPMB_2020_Annual_Report_press_release.pdf) by Global Preparedness and Monitoring Board, investment of 5 dollars per person per year would be needed for preparedness.

From : [The best time to prevent the next pandemic is now: countries join voices for better emergency preparedness](https://www.who.int/news-room/detail/01-10-2020-the-best-time-to-prevent-the-next-pandemic-is-now-countries-join-voices-for-better-emergency-preparedness)

Comment: Depending on the severity of the illness which Mr Trump experiences, it may change his mind about a number of things, as it did Boris Johnson's - the value of WHO being one of them.

Comment: @WS2 I tried doing a search for “boris johnson view who changed "world health"” but didn’t find anything too specific - do you have any sources that specifically attributes Johnson changing his view about the WHO based on getting infected?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Well, I wasn't thinking specifically of BJ in relation to WHO. What I  meant was that his illness totally changed him in relation to the pandemic. Before he took ill, his attitude was lakadaisical at best - not dissimilar from Trump's. He has, for example, been widely criticised for not attending COBRA meetings back in Feb/Mar - as if the virus was nothing important to worry about. But since it nearly killed him, he has become more engaged, though many would argue, ineffectively. There is widespread belief that he does not possess the skill set to deal with a crisis.